# XSL-FO- Specifying conditional visibility

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an HTML table that varies according to its content.  1-3 columns hide.  1 column name changes.  All depending on content.

I am creating a PDF version of this HTML table.  The PDF version uses `apache-FOP` with `fop v1.0`.  The PDF output contains 2 of the aforementioned tables on one page.  I do not want to create an `.xsl` for every combination of possibilities.  That's a lot of duplication and maintenance.

I can solve the column name change simply by passing the column name in with the XML content.  But, conditional visibility of the columns seems to be a far more challenging task.

How can I setup conditional visibility?  Is it possible?

---

I'm having difficulty just getting `<fo:table-column visibility="collapse" />` to work.  The data still displays with visility set to hidden or collapse.  `display="none"` looked promising.  But, the [API doesn't show it as a valid property](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_table-column) for a table-column.

If I can't conditionally hide a column then I'll need to produce 18 unique `xsl` files...

---

Currently, my tables are very basic.  I do

```
<fo:block font-size="10pt">
  <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">
    <fo:table-column />
    <fo:table-column />
    <fo:table-column />
    <fo:table-column />
    <fo:table-column />
    <fo:table-column visibility="collapse" />
    <fo:table-column />
    <fo:table-column />
    <fo:table-column />
    <fo:table-column />
    <fo:table-header>
      <fo:table-cell border-width="0.2mm" border-style="solid">
        <fo:block>Header 1</fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      //...9 other headers (these should show/hide as needed)
    </fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-body>
      <xsl:for-each select="Object/type/SomeItem/ProcedureItemCollection">
        <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell border-width="0.2mm" border-style="solid" >
            <fo:block>
              <xsl:value-of select="content1"/>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          //...9 other cells...
        </fo:table-row>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
</fo:block>
```

XML

```
<Procedure>
  <SiteName>Site1</SiteName>//If Site1, don't create column 2
                            //If Site2, don't create column 2,3,4
                            //If Site3, create all columns
   <itemtype1>
            <item><member1></member1><member2></member2></item>
            <item><member1></member1><member2></member2></item>
   </itemtype1>
   <itemtype2>
            <item><member1></member1><member2></member2></item>
            <item><member1></member1><member2></member2></item>
   </itemtype2>
</Procedure>
```

Doing it this way, I have little flexibility in creating the table.  But, this is all I know how to do.

Comment: How do you solve the problem in the HTML version of the table?

Comment: @mzjn - I created a custom class `TableHelper`.  The class represents an HTML table with a header, rows and footer member.  Then I pass the data to my front end which just iterates what is there (an asp.net MVC-3 partial view does this), creating the table header, rows and footer dynamically.  I don't know if I can use this same concept to dynamically create entire tables in XSLT.

Comment: You can generate tables dynamically using XSLT if you want to. But I don't quite understand exactly what the problem is and how your toolchain works. How do you create the XSL-FO markup now? Why do you think that you need "18 unique xsl files"? Do you already use XSLT, or do you want to know if you can use it?

Comment: OK, you do use XSLT. Please show us what the source XML looks like. We can't help without that. Please also explain what the conditions are, and what the logic behind "as needed" is.

Comment: @mzjn - Please see updated question.  I have to create 18 tables because of some details that don't matter.  If you can show me how to conditionally create a column (or show/hide) based on the value of `<SiteName>` then you have answered the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering it turns out that I can add/remove columns using `xsl:when` and a variable.

First create a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="SiteName" select="Procedure/SiteName" />
```

Then conditionally create the 3 elements of the table (column definition, header, body). Starting with the column definition...

```
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$SiteName = 'Site1'">
              <fo:table-column />//column 2
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
```

Then the header

```
           <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$SiteName = 'Site1'">
                    <fo:table-cell border-width="0.2mm" border-style="solid">
                      <fo:block>Column2</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
```

Finally, the body

```
                <xsl:choose>                                           
                        <xsl:when test="$SiteName = 'Site1'">
                          <fo:table-cell border-width="0.2mm" border-style="solid" >
                            <fo:block>
                              <xsl:value-of select="column2value"/>
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                        </xsl:when>                          
                </xsl:choose>
```